# CardView is not showing Youtube Thumbnail view in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, youtube, android-recyclerview

I have used the Youtube API in my application along with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and RecyclerView and for some reasons my YouTube Thumbnail is not being shown in my application although I have added it in my `CardView` and my `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` has code to access the `CardView` but when I start my application and go to that activity no thumbnail is shown over there. I have implemented it as hard coded without Firebase Adapter.

**Steps I have tried:**

1. Added layout manager
2. Adjusting the height and width of cardView and thumbnailView

I am using Android Studio

**YouTube class file:**

```java
public class YoutubeVideos extends YouTubeBaseActivity {

    private RecyclerView YouRecycler;
    private DatabaseReference YDatabaseReference;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.youtube_videos);
        YDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("youtubed");
        YouRecycler = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.Youtube_recycler);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post2youtube, YoutubeViewHolder> YfirebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post2youtube, YoutubeViewHolder>(

            post2youtube.class,
            R.layout.youtube_videos_card,
            YoutubeViewHolder.class,
            YDatabaseReference
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(YoutubeViewHolder viewHolder, post2youtube model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setYoutube(model.getYoutube());
        }

    };

            YouRecycler.setAdapter(YfirebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }    


    public static class YoutubeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View yView;

        public YoutubeViewHolder(View YitemView) {
            super(YitemView);
            yView = YitemView;
        }
        public void setYoutube(final String youtube){
            final YouTubePlayerView youPlay = (YouTubePlayerView) yView.findViewById(R.id.youtuber);
            youPlay.initialize("Some key",
                    new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(youtube);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                        }

                    });
        }

    }
}
```

**YouTube RecyclerView file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id ="@+id/Youtube_recycler"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**YouTube cardView xml file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtuber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

YoutubePlayer view is too large to be added to a recyclerview.So use a YouTubeThumbnailView instead to display the thumbnails. When the user clicks on one of them, you can start a YouTubePlayerFragment or an activity with a YouTubeplayerView view.

below is the reference code,

in xml :

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                    android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ten_dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

in java :

```
// Initializing video player with developer key
   youtube_view.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, final YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
         youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(videoId);
         youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {
             @Override
             public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                 youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "It's a valid youtube url.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             @Override
             public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {
                 try {
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Not a valid youtube url.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     } catch (Exception ex) {
                          ex.printStackTrace();
                     }
                }
               });
             }
             @Override
             public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            }
       });
```

Comment: `Config` is showing an error of cannot resolve symbol, how to remove it

Comment: I have solved config but it is still not showing, also anything which i am placing in card view is not getting shown

Comment: Config is a class in which DEVELOPER_KEY is static constant you ca use any other class also in place of Config

Comment: after adding the thumbnail view it is not showing in the application.